# Get non-expiring permanent amazon s3 object url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

My code looks like this:

```
module Operations
  class UploadFileToS3 < MethodStruct.new(:params)
    def call
      s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['S3_REGION'])
      obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object(object_name)
      obj.upload_file(params[:tempfile_path],
                      content_type: params[:content_type],
                      acl: 'public-read')
      {
        url: obj.presigned_url(:get),
        # url: obj.public_url,
        filename: object_name
      }
    end

    private

    def object_name
      "#{params[:timestamp]}-#{params[:uuid]}#{params[:thumbname_suffix]}"
    end
  end
end
```

For all uploaded files, the following properties are set automatically:

```
Expiry Date: None
Expiration Rule: N/A
```

Uploaded objects's `Permissions` include:

```
Everyone: Open/Download
```

Bucket's `Permissions` include:

```
Everyone: View Permissions
```

Bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKETNAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Commented out `obj.public_url` returns bare link to object (no query string attached), which expires as well and then renders xml file. Bare link taken straight from the object props expires too, even if I manually add to the object's `Permissions`:

```
Everyone: View Permissions
```

Even if I make an object public via AWS console, the link it gives me includes header `X-Amz-Expires=300`.

Trying to use `obj.presigned_url(:get, acl: 'public-read')` throws `ArgumentError - unexpected value at params[:acl]`.

I would like to use this bucket as storage for avatars so everyone should be able to see the linked picture at all times. Any ideas how to get the really permanent url that will not expire nor today neither in one year?

Comment: have you tried this obj.url_for(:read) or obj.url_for(:read, :expires => some_really_big_number)

Comment: Hey @Zahid, the documentation specifies maximum `expires` as one year, which is still a finite period. If you set `expires` to be more than one year, it should be ignored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the ACL of the object is `public-read` then the non-expiring URL for the object is simply this:

```
http[s]://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.ext
```

> bare link to object (no query string attached), which expires as well and then renders xml file

No, it doesn't.  You have made an error in your observations, or you are looking at a cached response.  A URL with no query string has no possible mechanism that would cause it to expire.  Note the RequestId and HostId in the xml.  If they are not changing, you are dealing with a cached response, because they *always* change from response to response from S3.

Comment: One can get this URL from the AWS SDK by using `S3::Object`s `#public_url` method:

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify acl like public_read could be a symbol or string

```
  obj.upload_file(params[:tempfile_path],
                  content_type: params[:content_type],
                  acl: :public_read)
  {
    url: obj.public_url,
    filename: object_name
  }
```

Updated code

```
obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object(object_name)
obj.write(:file => image_location)
obj.acl = :public_read
obj.public_url.to_s
```

Otherwise private permission is being set.

Comment: Hey @Zahid, the documentation specifies `acl` values very precisely as strings, and one of them is `public-read`. Passing symbol throws the same error as in my original description, i.e. `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Okay, can you tell which gem you are using, I thought you were using aws-sdk

Comment: Yes, I am using `aws-sdk` in version `2.1.20`. Please check here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html#acl-instance_method. All around this documentation you can find info such as `:acl (String) — The canned ACL to apply to the object.`

Comment: @Zahid your answer is incorrect for version 2 of aws-sdk. The acl symbols are no longer valid.
Also `Aws::S3::Object` does not have `#write`. You have to use `#put` instead.
And finally, the acl is no longer set by a writer but through `obj.acl.put`.